# Using the Xbox 360 wireless adapter on vista

Tags: windows-vista, drivers, wireless-networking, xbox360

I am in a position where i will no longer have wired access for my desktop PC and so i will need to go wireless, Is it possible to use the Xbox 360 wireless adapter on my computer instead of spending the money to buy one?

Answer (score 1):

The XBox Wireless adapters are just a generic USB wireless device.  Windows should have some drivers to support it, as the XBox is just a Windows computer (all be it running a very custom version of Windows).

It's worth a shot to try it.  You won't damage it by trying.

Comment: I have tried that and it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: They you may need to go pick up a USB WiFi card.  They shouldn't be that expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to plug it in and it should go. I have seen it done before, but I can't seem to find anything on the internet to back this up.

Plug it in and it should just "work" or like my 5 year old like to refer to it as "computer magic" :)

Answer (score 0):

On Vista 64bit this doesn't work, unfortunately. I've had a look trying to find drivers myself but can't seem to find any specifically for it.

Answer (score 0):

It's highly unlikely that this will work at all. Microsoft does *not* like their components being used across different platforms (ie the Xbox 360 controller will not work on a Windows PC, you must by the '360 controller for Windows).

However, if it *does* work, it is most likely to work on a 32-bit system, especially a Vista/7 system that will go out and download drivers for you. It will most definitely not work on a 64 bit machine.

So basically, it most likely is not possible.

Comment: interesting... I had my xbox 360 controller (wired) working on Windows XP playing Super Metroid in an emulator, XP recognized the device and dl'd the drivers to make it work... it was a while back that I did it though, never tried with Vista.

Answer (score 0):

To use an Xbox 360 wireless adapter on Windows you need to purchase a [Wireless Gaming Receiver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_360_accessories#Wireless_Gaming_Receiver). You can find them on Ebay for ~15$.